# Pdf file doesn't load using groovy class loader

Tags: groovy

Problem loading a file using groovy. I've a `sample.txt` file and a pdf (`fonts.pdf`) file in my testdata for a project. They are located in the same path.

When I use the code below to get the txt file I do not get a `NullPointerException` but when I use the same code to get a pdf file I get a `NullPointerException`.

```
     def String inputFile = 'fonts.pdf'
     GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader()
     return new File(classLoader.getResource(inputFile).path)
```

Comment: show the full script please

Answer (score 0):

Are you using script with package name?  Following worked without any problem.

```
def String inputFile = 'fonts.pdf'
 GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader()
 print classLoader.getResource(inputFile );
 return new File ( classLoader.getResource(inputFile ).toURI() )
```

If I use packages then file name need to have matching package name and should reside in appropriate runtime location

```
def String inputFile = 'apackage/fonts.pdf'
 GroovyClassLoader classLoader = new GroovyClassLoader()
 print classLoader.getResource(inputFile );
 return new File ( classLoader.getResource(inputFile ).toURI() )
```

In any case I did not see difference if file was text or pdf